# Compare 2 result sets without INTERSECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have 2 tables :-

```
ITEM(ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME)

STATS(ITEM_ID, STAT_ID, STAT_VALUE)
```

I would like to return the `ITEM_IDs` with exactly the same `STATS`, but it is on SQL Server Compact(no `EXCEPT` or `INTERSECT`)

For example :

```
STATS:-
1 12 100 
1 13 500
2 12 200
2 14 300
3 12 100
3 13 500
4 12 100
```

Should returns the lines for 1 and 3 (same stats/values 12/100 and 13/500)

Is it possible without `INTERSECT`?

Comment: Are those columns NULLable?

Comment: How do you use `INTERSECT` for that results? ;).

Comment: What if there's a row `5 13 500`, should this be included in the result or only if there's   `5 12 100`, too?

Comment: 5 13 500 would need 5 12 100 to be included (exact same stats as 1 and 3)

Comment: So what you're looking for is "finding equal sets". How many rows are in the `ITEMS` and `STATS` table?

Comment: In the real tables, STATS has 200K rows and ITEM 100K but I'm actually testing with the tables I've given for the sample. That's why I've added the line with ITEM_ID=4 that I try to exclude from the result (missing 13/500)

Answer (score 4):

use inner join in ITEM table and use on condition for whatever you want to see on that table

Answer (score 3):

I got it totally wrong the first time :-)

The standard approaches to "finding equal sets" are hard to understand and performance is usually bad for large tables as they involve comparing everything with everything else (similar to CROSS JOINs).

AFAIK SQL Server CE supports XML functions, too, so best way is the one described by Vladimir Baranov in one of the existing answers:

```
with cte as
 ( -- group concat all rows for one ITEM_ID into one big string
   SELECT distinct ITEM_ID,
     (select '#' + rtrim(STAT_ID) + ',' + rtrim(STAT_VALUE) 
      from STATS as t2 
      where t1.ITEM_ID = t2.ITEM_ID ORDER BY STAT_ID FOR XML PATH('') ) as rowsConcat
   FROM STATS as t1
 ),
cnts as
 ( -- how many rows exist for that concatenated string?
   select *
     ,count(*) 
      over (partition by rowsConcat) as cnt
   from cte
 ) 
select ITEM_ID
  ,dense_rank() -- assign the same group number to the duplicates 
   over(order by rowsConcat) as duplicateGroup
from cnts
where cnt > 1 -- more than one
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/23505/13)

Comment: The idea seems good, but SQL Server CE is very limited and it doesn't support "FOR XML". But I will continue to search in this direction... Thanks.

Comment: @Fred: I assumed that CE is similar to the Express version, CE seems to be very limited, no CTE, no ROW_NUMBER. Search for `sql "equal sets"` and you'll find some excerpts from a Joe Celko book, answer #5 should be possible with CE,  but performance might be horrible...

Comment: @dnoeth, thanks for mentioning the Joe Celko's book. I found it and it is worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would approach such task.

**Step 1.** Have a function/method to combine values in several columns into one column. In your case we want to put two values `STAT_ID` and `STAT_VALUE` together. In this case simple conversion to string and concatenation should be enough. So, a row with two columns:

```
STAT_ID STAT_VALUE
12      100
```

becomes a row with one column:

```
single_value
12_100
```

Result of this transformation should be the table like this:

```
ITEM_ID single_value
1       12_100 
1       13_500
2       12_200
2       14_300
3       12_100
3       13_500
4       12_100
```

**Step 2.** Have some Aggregate function that accepts values in several rows and returns one value as a long concatenated string. It could be a CLR function, a T-SQL function or `FOR XML` construct. You can choose one depending on what SQL Server CE supports.

Result of this transformation should be the table like this:

```
ITEM_ID aggregated_single_value
1       12_100__13_500
2       12_200__14_300
3       12_100__13_500
4       12_100
```

**Step 3.** Once you have this result you can simply `GROUP BY aggregated_single_value` and `COUNT` how many `ITEM_IDs` with exactly same set of values you have. Then return only those `ITEM_IDs` that are `HAVING` count more than 1.

```
aggregated_single_value  Count
12_100__13_500           2
12_200__14_300           1
12_100                   1
```

**Edit**

The overall approach still holds with limitations of SQL Server CE.

- It doesn't have Common-Table-Expressions - use explicit temporary tables for each step.
- It doesn't have `FOR XML`, user-defined functions, CLR - do the aggregation "manually". It looks like it [supports cursors](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172364(v=sql.110).aspx). Open the cursor - scan the table once with proper order, aggregate values and save them to temporary table.
- Does it support large types like `varbinary(max)` or `varchar(max)`? If yes - great, if no - you'll be limited to `varchar(8000)` or `varbinary(8000)`. If you have at most two (or so) rows for the same `ITEM_ID` in the `STATS` table, then 8000 bytes is enough.

Also, there is at least one simple crude way to limit the number of rows processed by the cursor. At first do simple count of rows for each `ITEM_ID` in the `STATS` table and leave only those `IDs` that have a matching count. In other words, filter out obvious mismatches. This step would eliminate `ID=4` from your example.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but SQL Server CE doesn't seem to support anything to aggregate rows directly...

Comment: Does it have user-defined functions? Basically, you need to find a way to do `group-concat` for your version of SQL Server. By the way, what is the exact version of your server?

Comment: It is SQL Server CE 4.0 , many "not supported" features : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: I added few notes on how you would be able to work around the limitations of SQL Server CE.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if `SQL Server Compact` supports inner queries, but this concept should work:

```
select distinct a.item_id 
       from  stats a 
       where exists(select 1 
                           from stats b 
                           where a.stat_d=b.stat_id 
                            and a.stat_value=b.stat_value)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will return unwanted rows like 4 (12/100 exists but not  13/500)

Answer (score 2):

> **`INTERSECT`**
>   Returns any distinct values that are returned by both the query on the left and right sides of the `INTERSECT` operand.

Alternative of using `INTERSECT` is using `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A   -- [A: ID, Name]
INTERSECT
SELECT B.*
FROM B  -- [B: ID, Name]
```

Is equal to

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM A
JOIN (
    SELECT B.*
    FROM B) B1 ON A.ID = B1.ID AND A.Name = B1.Name
```

or by using `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM B WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND A.Name = B.Name)
```

---

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.STAT_ID, s1.STAT_VALUE
FROM STATS s1
    JOIN
    STATS s2 ON s1.ITEM_ID <> s2.ITEM_ID 
            AND s1.STAT_ID = s2.STAT_ID 
            AND s1.STAT_VALUE = s2.STAT_VALUE
```

Comment: Same problem as the first answer : this will return unwanted rows (1 line exists but not the other)

Comment: @Fred If I know `How do you use INTERSECT for that results?` I can help you more, here I show some ways for you to don't use `INTERSECT` ;).

Comment: I've precised this because I usually used INTERSECT with others SGBD for these types of queries  (ORACLE, Sybase, etc...) and it is not on SQL CE.

Comment: @Fred OK, So for example please give me your query in Sybase ;).

Comment: Maybe INTERSECT doesn't work in this case : I just wanted to exclude answers with INTERSECT :-)